# Get a yes, no, or nothing out of a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, function, search, if-statement

Im trying to get either a Yes, No or nothing out of a cell in excel.

If i try the code below it will print "Yes" or " " but it will not print "No"

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Y",F3),"Yes",IF(SEARCH("n",F3),"No","")),"")
```

cell F3 has

```
Y - D3
```

or

```
N - D3
```

It works fine with the following code, but it won't search for the string

```
=IFERROR(IF(F3="Y","Yes",IF(F3="N","No","")),"")
```

"N" and "Y" work but "Y - D3" doesn't

Any comments are appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use any IF() functions at all:

```
=REPT("Yes",LEFT(F3,1)="y")&REPT("No",LEFT(F3,1)="n")
```

This article might interest you: [I Heart IF](http://blog.excelhero.com/2010/01/21/i_heart_if/)

Comment: Here is what i have working!   =IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("n",F3),"No",""),IF(SEARCH("y",F3),"Yes")),"")

Comment: Speaking as the rubber duck, and I understand you may have simplified the case for the question, but I'm curious to know what you want to have happen if the string contains both a Y and an N? In your current solution it would be "No," just not sure if that's precisely what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you step through the formula, you'll see that it's generating an error, which is short-circuiting your formula.  Try wrapping the conditions in a Not and ISERROR and see if it gives you the expected results.  Something like:

```
=IFERROR(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Y",F3))),"Yes",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("n",F3))),"No","")),"")
```

I'm sure the formula could be simplified, but hopefully this at least gets your started...

Answer (score 1):

If you surround with an ISNUMBER then it should work.

Like so:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",F3)),"Yes",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("N",F3)),"No","")),"")
```